# Free and bound charges understanding & the Displacement Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dielectric

This will be to a certain extend a bit lengthy, because I am confused about several aspects when it comes to electrostatics in dielectrics. I think it  boils down to an imprecise notation and explanation of terms and concepts. I really want to understand the electrodynamics in medium and if I would be able to finally have answers for the below listed questions, that would truly help me, finally, to understand the physics of it. I am trying to understand two things:

1. Conceptual understanding the difference between the two types of charges and how they are geometrically positioned in an arbitrary set up that we observe and how is each type related to some field via the Gauss law. I'd like to illustrate what I mean with a simple example.
2. Where is the $\vec D(\vec r)$ field present? Inside the dielectric, outside of it, if it is inside the dielectric, which doesn't have free charges, how we justify the existence of $\vec D$ then?
   The example:

We have a plate capacitor, that has a certain $E_{ext}(\vec r)$ electric field between the two plate. Now, if we were to put a dielectric between the two plates, under the affect of the external electric field we would induce a polarization of the material which leads ,in the easiest case of hom. polarisation, into an internal electric field ,because of the charges in the surface of it, and this internal electric field $\vec E(\vec r)_{int}$ has the opposite direction of the external one. Hence the resulting $\vec E(\vec r)$ field is:

$$\vec E(\vec r)_{tot}=\vec E(\vec r)=E_{ext}(\vec r)+\vec E(\vec r)_{int}$$

The relationship between the electric field (I assume this is the resulting ele. Field) and the electric displacement is:

$$\vec D(\vec r)=\epsilon_0 \vec E(\vec r)+\vec P(\vec r)$$

**Question 1** : The electric field in the above equation, is the one that is inside the dielectric (as a result of the external and internal) ? I ask this because if we consider the above formula and we want to find the $\vec D$ field outside the dielectric, in the space between the plates (in our example) then the polarisation vanishes and we end up with $\vec D = \epsilon_0 \vec E$, but if $\vec E$ is the resultant electric field inside the dielectric, it doesn't make sense to consider this when we want to find the $\vec D$ field outside of it, because outside of the dielectric $\vec E(\vec r)_{internal}$ doesn't exist.

In our notes it is said that the total charges are the source of the $\vec E$  The bound charges are the source of the polarsation field (which I assume is another way of saying the internal electric field that arises because of the polarisation of the dielectric under the influence of the external field ) and the bound charges the source of the electric displacement $\vec D(\vec r)$. In other words:

$$\epsilon_0\nabla \vec E(\vec r)=\rho(\vec r)_{total}$$

$$\nabla \vec P=\rho(\vec r)_{bound}$$

$$\nabla \vec D(\vec r)=\rho(\vec r)_{free}$$

**Question 2:** Having in mind our set up, that of a plate capacitor with an dielectric in between. If we were to apply the Gauss law for the electric field, what would we get? If the region of the integration was the dielectric, would we get zero, since the total charge enclosed is zero (dielectric is neutral)? Or do we need to integrate over a region which includes the charges in the plates of the capacitor, which are the free charges?

**Question 3:** This is the most important question for me, since it's directly linked with the 2nd thing I want to understand. Does it make sense to use Gass's law for the $\vec D$ for a volume that encloses the dielectric? Shouldn't we get zero as a result, because no free charge is enclosed in this volume? If the answer is no, meaning that the $\vec D$ is different from zero when we consider a volume in the dielectric, then, since $\vec D$ has the free charges as it's source, that would indicate free charges in the dielectric? If the answer is yes, then what is the point of considering a field inside of an dielectric, when this field is zero inside of it?

I hope, someone can give me answers to these 3 questions. I consider them very important in my understanding of the D field, free and bound charges etc.

Thanks!